# Enterprise Library logging to filter by category like some value

Tags: c#, .net, logging, enterprise-library

I've been looking around for documentation regarding enterprise library 5.0 logging and filtering but couldn't find anything related to my scenario, outside of the enterprise library CHM.

I have a few types of categories being logged and I want to filter the logging to pick up only certain categories. 
Say I have these categories General,Turtle, Rhino.A, Rhino.B, Rhino.C etc lots of Rhinos.

I want to only pick up categories like Rhino.**__**

what I believe I did was filter for anything not General or Turtle, however I rather try to pick up anything that's like Rhino.**__**
Even some documentation about this would be helpful.

This is my current config.

```
<loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="false">
  <listeners>
    <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter" log="" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="None" />
    <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"
         type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
         fileName="AppLog.log"
         formatter="Short Text Formatter" header="------------------------------------------------------" footer="------------------------------------------------------"
         rollInterval="Day" rollSizeKB="1024"
         timeStampPattern="yyyy-MM-dd"
         rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment"
         traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime" />
  </listeners>
  <formatters>
    <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" template="Timestamp: {timestamp(local)}{newline}App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}Machine: {localMachine}{newline}Title:{title}{newline}Severity: {severity}{tab}Message: {message}{newline}Category: {category}{newline}ProcessId: {localProcessId}{tab}Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}Thread Name: {threadName}{tab}ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}&#xA;" name="Text Formatter" />
  </formatters>
  <logFilters>
    <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.CategoryFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      categoryFilterMode="AllowAllExceptDenied" name="Category Filter">
      <categoryFilters>
        <add name="General" />
        <add name="Turtle" />
      </categoryFilters>
    </add>
  </logFilters>
  <categorySources>
    <add switchValue="All" name="General" />
    <add switchValue="All" name="Turtle" />
  </categorySources>
  <specialSources>
    <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
    <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
      <listeners>
        <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
      </listeners>
    </notProcessed>
    <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
      <listeners>
        <add name="Event Log Listener" />
      </listeners>
    </errors>
  </specialSources>
</loggingConfiguration>
```

The filtering looks as so, and I'm capturing everything but General and Turtle, which works but seems a little concerning because I rather capture only things like Rhino.**__** to be absolutely sure the log is clean of other categories.

```
<logFilters>
<add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.CategoryFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
  categoryFilterMode="AllowAllExceptDenied" name="Category Filter">
  <categoryFilters>
    <add name="General" />
    <add name="Turtle" />
  </categoryFilters>
</add>
</logFilters>
<categorySources>
    <add switchValue="All" name="General" />
    <add switchValue="All" name="Turtle" />
</categorySources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Enterprise Library does not support your scenario directly. You may have to implement a Custom Logging Filter.

Here is what it might look like (this is untested code):

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters;
using System;
using System.Linq;

[ConfigurationElementType(typeof (CustomLogFilterData))]
public class RhinoFilter : LogFilter
{
    public RhinoFilter(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }

    public RhinoFilter(NameValueCollection settings) 
        : this("RhinoFilter")
    {
    }

    public override bool Filter(LogEntry log)
    {
        return log.Categories.Any(x => x.StartsWith("Rhino."));
    }
}
```